# ACCESS SQL Inner Join

Tags: sql, ms-access, inner-join

I have a table similar to this with internal relationships:

```
BOM         CMP   CMPTYPE
1           JTS   A
1           RED   PT
1           BLUE  PT
2           QQ    PT
2           ZZ    PT
JTS         33    PT
JTS         55    PT
JTS         WID   A
WID         LOG   PT
WID         191   DWG
WID         BOX   PACK
.           .     .
```

In my query I need to select all records where BOM="1" and also all records where a sub-configuration of BOM="1" exists, indicated in the table as CMPTYPE="A".

Here is an accurate representation of the configuration I am after:

```
1   RED  PT
1   BLUE PT
1   JTS  A
JTS 33   PT
JTS 55   PT
JTS WID  A
WID LOG  PT
WID 191  DWG
WID BOX  PACK
```

Can this be done in a single Access Inner join?

Comment: I probably don't understand, but are you just wanting those cases where `BOM=1 AND CMPTYPE='A'`?

Comment: Why are the `WID` records in your output?

Comment: Or are you wanting all rows where `BOM=1` and all `BOM` where there exists `CMPTYPE="A"`?

Comment: So you take all records with BOM = 1 and then if CMPTYPE = A you take all records where BOM = CMP of those rows (JTS in this case) and then if that has any CMPTYPE = A you do it again?  Do you do it forever or just once?

Comment: If it is a specific number of times you can do it with joins.  If it is infinite recursion you can't in Access.  You could in a platform that supports recursive CTEs.

Comment: trincot - WID is a subitem of JTS which is a subitem of 1.

Comment: hogan - Infinite recursion is what I am after as the number of subitem levels could be between 0 to as many as 20, though likely usually 5 or 6.

Comment: hogan - if I set the number of times to 5 how would I structure the query?

Comment: can I use access vba to implement recursive cte?

Answer (score 0):

If you're okay to use VBA, you can definitely do it.

Here's example using your data structure above

First **create a query** (*replacing "Table1" with your "TableName"*)

Save as qdfInitQuery

```
PARAMETERS [Init BOM] Text ( 255 ), [Init CMPType] Text ( 255 );
SELECT CMP
FROM Table1
WHERE (BOM=[Init BOM]) AND (CMPTYPE=[Init CMPType]);
```

The **enter this cod**e in a new Module

```
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub testConfig()

    ConfigSelect BOMValue:="1", CMPTypeValue:="A"

End Sub


Public Sub ConfigSelect(BOMValue As String, CMPTypeValue As String)

    Const MY_TABLE      As String = "Table1" ' replace with  your Table name here

    Const REPLACE_LIST  As String = "<ListOfBOMs>"
    Const SELECT_CMPS   As String = "SELECT CMP FROM [" & MY_TABLE & "] WHERE [BOM] In (" & REPLACE_LIST & ")"
    Const VALID_RECORDS As String = "SELECT * FROM [" & MY_TABLE & "] WHERE [BOM] In (" & REPLACE_LIST & ")"

    Dim db          As DAO.Database
    Dim rs          As DAO.Recordset
    Dim qdf         As DAO.QueryDef

    Dim strList     As String
    Dim strBigList  As String
    Dim strSQL      As String

    Set db = CurrentDb

    ' Add First Value
    strList = ","

    ' Get Initial List
    Set qdf = db.QueryDefs("qdfInitQuery")
    With qdf
        .Parameters("Init BOM") = "1"
        .Parameters("Init CMPType") = "A"
        Set rs = .OpenRecordset(dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)
    End With
    With rs
        While Not .EOF
            strList = strList & """" & !CMP & """," 'leave trailing comma for searches
            .MoveNext
        Wend
        .Close
    End With
    qdf.Close

    If strList = "," Then
        Exit Sub
    End If

    ' Create Big List
    strBigList = strList

    ' Infinite Loop until No More Matches Found
    Do Until strList = ","
        strSQL = Replace(SELECT_CMPS, REPLACE_LIST, Mid$(strList, 2))
        Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)
        If rs.EOF Then
            rs.Close
            Exit Do
        End If

        strList = ","
        With rs
            While Not .EOF
                ' Only Add if it hasn't already been found
                If InStr(strBigList, ",""" & !CMP & """,") <= 0 Then
                    strList = strList & """" & !CMP & """," ' leave trailing comma for searches
                Else
                    Debug.Print "Ignoring Duplicate: " & !CMP
                End If
                .MoveNext
            Wend
            .Close
        End With

        If strList <> "," Then
            strBigList = strBigList & Mid$(strList, 2)
        End If
    Loop

    ' Add first value to initial list
    strBigList = """" & BOMValue & """" & strBigList

    strSQL = Replace(VALID_RECORDS, REPLACE_LIST, strBigList)
    Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenSnapshot, dbReadOnly)
    With rs
        While Not .EOF
            ' Only Add if it hasn't already been found
            Debug.Print !BOM & vbTab & !CMP & vbTab & !CMPType
            .MoveNext
        Wend
        .Close
    End With

    db.Close
    Set rs = Nothing
    Set qdf = Nothing
    Set db = Nothing

End Sub
```

Comment: dbmitch - Thanks. Will review and post on progress.

Comment: Any problems in implementation?